# vertex or set of vertices reachable from all other vertices in a directed graph

Tags: graph

Given a directed graph  how to find vertex(call it "special vertex") that can be reached from all other vertices? It is not necessary that other vertices have to be reachable from this special vertex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would assume the graph is acyclic (i.e. a DAG)

- 1) do topological ordering over the graph 2) check the indegree of the last vertex. If it equals `n-1` then it is a special vertex. Of course here topological ordering without transitive closure is useless.
- One can argue that a vertex is special vertex if it is a
  leaf in the DAG.
- Reverse the arcs of the directed graph and run DFS on any vertex, If all other vertices are reachable, then this is a special vertex for the original graph.

Comment: i think, in-degree=n does not always imply this.
consider a graph 1->2, 2->3, 3->4 , topological order from graph would be 1 2 3 4. here the last vertex(i.e 4) has in-degree = 1.

Comment: @BodhAlmast of course you need to have the transitive closure (reachability relation)